# Output Component With A While Loop Even If The Component Content Is Empty - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, isset

I have a `while` loop that outputs three images onto an image preview board. This aspect is all working OK. I would like it so that if a preview board has no allocated images it still outputs the board component, but displays a message such as 'Add images to this board'.

In the code below, if the board preview component (the `<figure>`element) is empty, it currently outputs an unwanted single empty `<img>` tag. I thought I could fix this by changing this code block:

```
if ($imgcount < 3) { 
    echo "
        <img src='{$dbImageFile}'>
    ";
}
```

to this:

```
// only allow 3 images per board
if ($imgcount < 3 && isset($dbImageFile)) { 
    echo "
        <img src='{$dbImageFile}'>
    ";
}

// echo empty string if no image for this board
if ($imgcount < 3 && !isset($dbImageFile)) { 
    echo "";
}
```

...which I thought would output an empty string instead of the unwanted single `<img>` tag if the board has no images allocated to it. This single image tag is missing the filename from its path (although I obviously want to stop this image tag being outputted completely)

And then at the end of the `while` loop, add the following message when there are no images (this is currently commented out in the main code)

```
if ($imgcount == 0 ) {
    echo "Add Images To This board";
}
```

In the MySQL code the `boards_images` table is a linking/pivot table that holds the board id and a related image id for that board.

```
<?php
    $s = "SELECT boards.board_name, boards.board_id, images.filename
    FROM boards
    LEFT JOIN boards_images on boards_images.board_id = boards.board_id
    LEFT JOIN images        on boards_images.image_id = images.image_id
    WHERE boards.user_id = :user_id
    ORDER BY boards.board_id";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($s);
    $stmt -> execute([
        ':user_id' => $db_id // $_SESSION login variable
    ]);

    $dbBoardname_last = '';
    $imgcount = 0;

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        $dbBoardId = htmlspecialchars($row['board_id']);
        $dbBoardname = htmlspecialchars($row['board_name']);
        $dbImageFile = htmlspecialchars($row['filename']);

        // close the previousboard component <figure>
        if($dbBoardname_last != '' && $dbBoardname != $dbBoardname_last) {
        echo "
            </figure>
        ";
        }

        //if the board name is the different to the previous one add the opening component tag
        if($dbBoardname != $dbBoardname_last) {
        
            //reset the image count for new boards
            $imgcount = 0;

            // output opening board component <figure>
            echo "
                <figure class='board-component'>
                    <h2>{$dbBoardname}</h2>
            ";
                
        }

        // only allow 3 images per board
        if ($imgcount < 3) { 
            echo "
                <img src='{$dbImageFile}'>
            ";
        }

        $imgcount+=1;
        
        //record the last board_name to check if a new board element should be created

        $dbBoardname_last = $dbBoardname;

        // *** IF NO IMAGES ARE PRESENT ECHO THE 'ADD IMAGES' MESSAGE ***
        // if ($imgcount == 0 ) {
        //     echo "Add Images To this board";
        // }

    } 
    
    // close the last board component element
    if ($dbBoardname_last != '') {
        echo "
        </figure>
        ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` gets all the records in the `boards` table, `INNER JOIN` only gets records in the `boards` table that have corresponding records in the `boards_images` table.

Comment: `if ($imgcount < 3 && isset($dbImageFile)) {` is true when `$dbImageFile` is an empty string. Provide a few examples of `$dbImageFile`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles firstly I've edited the question so it now shows `LEFT JOIN`. I don't know what you mean by 'provide a few examples of `$dbImageFile`'? A typical path for when images show would be `project/images/nameOfFile.jpeg` but when the board is empty the single empty `<img>` tag that is outputted only has a path that is `project/images/`...  is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a board has no images linked to it, MySQL populates the `filename` value with `NULL`. And, when a `NULL` value is passed to the PHP [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function, it [returns an empty string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#114085).

```
// when "filename" from the database is NULL, $dbImageFile is assigned an empty string.
$dbImageFile = htmlspecialchars($row['filename']);
```

Also PHP [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function returns `true` when it is passed a variable that contains an empty string. Therefore the condition `if ($imgcount < 3 && isset($dbImageFile)) {` writes the image tag when there is no image linked to the board.

When using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) you'll never get a `NULL`, and MySQL always returns "filename" as a declared variable, even when it is assigned `NULL`. That's why `isset()` does not do what you expect with `$dbImageFile`.

Either use the value, possibly containing `NULL`, returned in the MySQL results set. `$row['filename']`:

```
// only allow 3 images per board
if ($imgcount < 3 && isset($row['filename'])) { 
    echo "
        <img src='{$dbImageFile}'>
    ";
}
```

...or, check for an empty string, `"" !== $dbImageFile`:

```
// only allow 3 images per board
if ($imgcount < 3 && "" !== $dbImageFile) { 
    echo "
        <img src='{$dbImageFile}'>
    ";
}
```

This is all you need. You don't need the second `if` condition with another "less than 3 images written to the board" check, and if the `$dbImageFile` is not set: `!isset($dbImageFile)`:

1. `$dbImageFile` in your code will *always* return `true` when passed to `isset()` (is set).
2. `$dbImageFile` in your code will *always* return `false` when passed to `!isset()` (is not set).

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of tricky problem, because your query contains duplicates, in your case I would suggest to map the records at first and then looping them and print the HTML code

```
<?php
$boards = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $boards[$row['board_id']] = $boards[$row['board_id']] ?? [];
    $boards[$row['board_id']]['name'] = $row['board_name'];
    $boards[$row['board_id']]['images'] = $boards[$row['board_id']]['images'] ?? [];
    $boards[$row['board_id']]['images'][] = $row['filename'];
}

foreach ($boards as $board_id => $board) {
    echo '<figure>';
    echo $board['name'];
    $images_length = count($board['images']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < min($images_length, 3); $i++) {
        echo "<img src='{$board['images'][$i]}'>";
    }
    if ($images_length === 0) {
        echo "Add images to this board";
    }
    echo '</figure>';
}
```

Comment: how does my query contain duplicates? I've run the MySQL code in PHPmyAdmin and there aren't any duplicates?

Comment: What I meant is you have the same board name in each row (per board images)

Comment: Screenshot attached of the MySQL query (the filename doesn't include the file extension because this is currently concatenated on, but I've omitted that code from the question to reduce unnecessary code) 
 https://paste.pics/4b9592a6ac5d04a12ec6f109ffd6c339